# Set properties before calling the parent constructor

Tags: php, php-8

In some particular situations, we need to call the parent constructor `parent::__construct();` **after** properties initialization like the bellow code (Symfony Command code, for more details see [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html)):

```php
<?php

class CreateUserCommand extends Command
{
    // ...

    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;
    
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, bool $requirePassword = false)
    {
        // best practices recommend to call the parent constructor first and
        // then set your own properties. That wouldn't work in this case
        // because configure() needs the properties set in this constructor
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->requirePassword = $requirePassword;

        parent::__construct();
    }
```

I wonder how we can deal with this case if we make the Constructor in PHP 8 property promotion style :

```php
 <?php
 public function __construct(private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, private bool 
 $requirePassword = false)
 {
    parent::__construct();
 }
```

Comment: I'm confused. Firstly, the order you're asking for [is what PHP already does](https://3v4l.org/fnBTY): the properties are initialised before the body of the constructor is run, so before the parent construct call. Secondly, the properties in your example are private to the `CreateUserCommand`, so won't be visible in the parent constructor whichever order you run things in.